# How to implement removeAny in the Set ADT for a BST using active flags

Tags: java

I implemented the Set ADT using the standard approach with nodes (TreeNodes) using a binary search tree.

I have the task of implementing it using the same old nodes except that they have an additional boolean field "active", which can "switch on" (`setActive(true)`) or "switch off" (`setActive(false)`) the nodes when removing. This keeps removed nodes there, but they are ignored when we implement `toString()`, which returns the items in the set.

I was able to implement all the methods of the Set ADT apart from `removeAny()` (that removes anything from the set, essentially "switches it off"). The problem is that I have to find any node that is "switched on". For this, I have to go through each node and check if one is active. I tried to write the code using recursive calls, but got confused about what to return. Here is my attempt (in Java):

```
public T removeAny() throws Exception {
    if (size == 0) {
        throw new Exception ("You cannot remove anything since the set is empty!");
    }

    return removeAnyHelper (root);
} 

public T removeAnyHelper (OnOffTreeNode <T> node) {

    if (node == null) {
        return root.getValue();
    }

    if (node.getActive() == true) {
        size--;
        node.setActive(false);
        return node.getValue();
    }

    removeAnyHelper (node.getLeft());

    return removeAnyHelper (node.getRight());
}
```

How can I fix this method? What should I return?

I tried some if-statements to return both `removeAnyHelper (node.getLeft())` and `removeAnyHelper (node.getRight())`, but this didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

If the node is null, you presumably need to return null (since nothing was removed).

If the recursive call on the left child doesn't return null, it means we removed a node and we need to return it. Otherwise we need to return the result of the call on the right child.

Turning that into code:

```
public T removeAnyHelper (OnOffTreeNode <T> node) {
    if (node == null) {
        return null;
    }

    if (node.getActive()) { // == true is unnecessary
        size--;
        node.setActive(false);
        return node.getValue();
    }

    T removedNode = removeAnyHelper (node.getLeft());

    if (removedNode != null)
        return removedNode;
    else
        return removeAnyHelper (node.getRight());
}
```

Although I wouldn't really recommend using active/inactive flags for nodes in a BST - [deleting a node](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree#Deletion) isn't particularly hard to implement and avoids the problem of having a large number of inactive nodes.

More generally speaking, there are also [self-balancing BST's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree), which avoid reduced efficiency due to unbalanced trees.

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't think `removeAny` is a proper method for a `Set`, but anyway.

You can (and probably should) `removeAny` by removing the first leaf:

```
private T removeAnyHelper(OnOffTreeNode <T> node) {
    if (!present(node.getLeft() && !present(node.getRight())) {
        // no children -> this is a leaf, return
        node.setActive(false);
        return node.getValue();
    }
    // return left first, or right if left not present
    if (present(getLeft())) {
        return removeAnyHelper(getLeft());
    }
    return removeAnyHelper(getRight());
}

private boolean present(OnOffTreeNode<T> node) {
    return node != null || node.isActive();
}
```

Note that you also have a mistake in your base `removeAny` method because it doesn't check for root's active state:

```
public T removeAny() throws NoSuchElementException {
    if (size == 0 || !root.isActive()) {
        throw new NoSuchElementException ("cant remove");
    }
    return removeAnyHelper(root);
}
```